# How do I read an Excel Web Page?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Excel gives you the option to save as `Web Page (*.html, *.html)` which will convert your spreadsheet from the binary format to html.

It creates the html with the header:

```
<html 
    xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml"
    xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
    xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
```

A legacy third-party system being used is generating this html and saving it with the extension xls. Excel will open the file and although it gives a warning about "The file format and extension don't match" it opens the file just fine.

Currently, some VBA on on the end users personal macro workbook is reading these files and saving them to the binary Excel format.

```
Sub Convert()
      Const FOLDER_PATH As String = "Z:\reports\"
      Dim wb As Workbook
      Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FOLDER_PATH & "input.html.xls")
      wb.SaveAs Filename:=FOLDER_PATH & "output.xls", FileFormat:=xlExcel8
End Sub
```

However, the files are now being fed through a centralised process that handles all the report feeds.

The existing process reads reports in Java using poi. However, the process fails when being sent this Excel file as it is expecting xls and not html renamed as xls.

How do I read/convert these files in Java?

Comment: AFAIK not possible with apache poi. If you check the code of such a .htm file, you will see quite a bit of JavaScript code which apache poi can't process

Comment: Is the resulting `.xls` file readable as an `HSSFWorkbook`?

Comment: It isn't readable as an HSSFWorkbook, which is the way the other reports are being read.